# Missing detail page on hosting/server laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I've laravel app that sign to domain url https://brandztory.me/blog, so the app is uploaded to folder `/blog` on server that can be only access at that url..

For show list of the article it's good, there's no problem.. but when i go for detail of the article, it's shows this error

[image]

I don't know where's the problem, because on local, it's fine.. but when on server, this problem showed up..

Here's my Detail Method on Controller

```
public function detail(Request $request, $blogDetail)
    {
        $json = "json/blog.json";
        $blog = file_get_contents($json);
        $blog = json_decode($blog, true);
        $blog = array_filter($blog);
        $blog = collect($blog);
        $blogDetail = collect($blog)->where('judul_rtikel_slug', "{$blogDetail}");
        $results = collect($blog)->all();

        return view('pages/detailblog', compact('results', 'blogDetail'));
    }
```

Here's my route

```
Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@index');
Route::get('blog/{blogDetail}', 'BlogController@detail')->name('blog.view');
```

And here's my href route in blog view for go to detail page

```
{{ route('blog.view', ['blogDetail' => $row['judul_rtikel_slug']]) }}
```

I've looking for the problem, but no find a way out..

Comment: Not 100% sure but don't you need to use dot notation for views?

Comment: It's for calling route name..

Comment: What I mean is when you return view from the controller instead of pages/detailblog it should be pages.detailBlog. Look at this documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#nested-view-directories

Comment: Oh sorry, i've tried.. But it also same output of error

Comment: @Firqy17 make sure your web server works properly (url rewrites etc), eg. nginx https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-php-fpm-rewriting-for-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Check `$blogDetail` is it getting correct data or not with `dd()`.

Comment: Yes, showing correct data.. Is there any code that i have to put in detail route for because i put this laravel app in /url or /blog not on main domain/public_html ?